# “The most of” as in “the biggest portion”?

Tags: grammar, comparisons, superlative-degree

I am not sure if this type of usage of “the most of” is correct.
If someone can help clarify, I would really appreciate it.

- **Ex**: *Out of the three siblings, John received the most of the estate their father left.*

Is this an incorrect usage of “the most”? I was corrected by someone that I can’t use “the most” and “of” together to mean the majority share/largest portion of a given specific thing etc. is this advice correct? I see many Google results where such a combination is used.

For example, I found this following sentence from NHS.UK (Analysis by Bazian Edited by NHS Website):

- ... *the researchers compared what happened to the people who ate the most of the type of fat being studied, compared to the least.*

https://www.nhs.uk/news/heart-and-lungs/claims-that-butter-is-safe-and-margarine-deadly-are-simplistic/

If such is incorrect, should omitting the definite article “the” solve the problem and actually have the intended meaning of ‘largest portion/share or highest number of’ the given thing?

Thank you.

Comment: Article usage is complex and subtle. I'm trying to work out why I find the second example acceptable but not the first.  I think it's because in the first example we're talking about 'most of a specified quantity / commodity {John received _88% of the estate_}, so no article. Whereas in the second, it's {_Fat 28B: the Elbonians ate the most, the Klingans the least_ – so no specified quantity of fat}, so 'ate the most when it comes to 28B'. I'd say your advisor has it right.